# UPDATE using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table, **TABLE1**, which can be presented by:

```
select * from TABLE1 order by id_conv
```

Such as:

```
id_conv
=======
200
201
202
```

Another table **TABLE2** which can be presented by:

```
select * from TABLE2 order by id
```

Such as:

```
id | id_conv
============
 1 | NULL
 2 | NULL
 3 | NULL
```

Now I want to update the table **TABLE2** with the values of **TABLE1**.

1st row value in **TABLE1** to 1st row in **TABLE2** 
2nd row value in **TABLE1** to 2nd row in **TABLE2** 
3rd row value in **TABLE1** to 3rd row in **TABLE3**

like:

```
id | id_conv
============
 1 | 200
 2 | 201
 3 | 202
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why did `a` go to `1` and not to `2` or `3`?

Comment: This is obviously not real data. What is the relationship between id and id_conv?

Comment: @GSerg I want just the first row value in TABLE1 to the first row in TABLE2

Comment: @kyan There is [no such thing](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19222/5203) as first row. Rows must be thought of as stored in a random order, unless an explicit `ORDER BY` is present.

Comment: @GSerg sorry about unclear. The 2 tables are presented by `ORDER BY`. I've modified my question for being more understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, you can assign numbers based on desired ordering for both tables and join on it for update

```
WITH CTE_Table1 AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_conv) RN --set desired ordering
    FROM Table1
)
,CTE_Table2 AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN --set desired ordering
    FROM Table2
)
UPDATE t2
SET t2.id_conv = t1.id_conv
FROM CTE_Table1 t1
INNER JOIN CTE_Table2 t2 on t1.RN = t2.RN
```